# How to deploy a multi zone next js site on vercel

Tags: next.js, vercel

I've built out a multi zone next js site following the docs but the docs are missing one key element. How to deploy it to a vercel. Everything works fine on local host and I went through building local to find errors come deployment time. Now I'd like to deploy it to vercel or some other service that can handle multi zones. Sorry for the long-winded question had to hit a character count to post.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: It's in the [Deployment docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/deploying/multi-zones) — use a monorepo and deploy like normal. There are links to an example repo and Vercel's monorepo docs in the page I linked above. If you want to deploy to some other hosting provider or cloud service, you'll need to be familiar with how reverse proxies work and do some configuration yourself.